# require.js compiled versioning

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I had moduar SPA with require.js. My version control was ...

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: "bust="+((document.querySelector('#mainRest') && document.querySelector('#mainRest').getAttribute('data-version')) || 'noVer')});
```

where including require js ...

```
<script id='mainRest' data-main="js/rest/main" src="js/rest/require.js" data-version="30062015"></script>
```

In the way above I had a parameter for downloading dependencies.

Now i have lot of dependencies (templates, views) and i have to compile my require.js structure into single js (using r.js). Of course now I don't have any dependencies except the main one compiled file.

**The question is**: How can I add version parameter to the compiled file?

```
<script data-main="js/rest/compiled" src="js/rest/require.js?ver1" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder but it is possible to set version directly through the "data-main" directive...

```
<script data-main="js/rest/compiled.js?ver=101" src="js/rest/require.js?ver1" ></script>
```